# JavaFX, Maven: Alternatives to JLink

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx, jlink

Currently I'm trying to create a runnable jar for my maven project. The problem is, that I use the automatic module itextpdf, which apparently cannot be used with jlink.

Are there alternatives for creating a runnable jar with javafx and maven in eclipse? I just can't figure out, how to make this work.

My POM.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Mpp_App</groupId>
  <artifactId>Mpp_App</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Dacemo</name>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>12</release>
        </configuration>

      </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <release>12</release>
            <jlinkImageName>mppapp</jlinkImageName>
            <mainClass>app.Start</mainClass>    
        </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>

  <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <!-- maven note: must manually exclude all ancestors
                see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jfoenix/jfoenix -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6</version>
</dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.15</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you maven jar plugin to create one fat jar ?

Comment: @Sambit If I do that, and try to run the executable jar, I get the error, that JavaFx runteime dependencies are missing

Comment: Look into this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing

Comment: @Sambit please create the tag [maven-jlink-plugin], thanks. More questions incoming due to new release!